# Image upload from url size limit

Tags: php, upload, filesize, image-upload

How to check if an image uploaded from url is less than 1MB? Currently I save the image using `file_put_contents()` and check the size of the saved image with `filesize()`. Is there a way to check the size before using `file_put_contents()` in order to prevent too big files from fetching?

Comment: you'd have to issue a separate HEAD request to get the content-length header, **BEFORE** you fetch the image. Otherwise you have to download the entire thing, then strlen() the image data.

Comment: But can't the `content-length` header be manipulated?

Comment: sure. but that's the ONLY way you can get anything about the size of the object the url is pointing at without fully downloading it. If you're worried about getting your server overwhelmed by someone pointing your script at a url that fires off a terabyte of data, but says it'll only be sending 512 bytes... then you should be using far more secure tools than "file_get_contents".

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm worried about. Can you give me some hints about those tools?